# SSRS 2005 Conditional Formatting for a Bar Graph?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Afternoon all,

I have a simple bar graph in SSRS 2005.  I wish to apply some conditional formatting to this bar graph but i am unable to get this working.

I believe that i should be able to add formmatting within the 'Chart Properties --> 'Data' tab --> 'Values' section? I have added the following code to the Expression editer but this doesnt work.  when i preview the report it shows the bar graph colour as green as this is the default pallette?

```
=IIF(fields!Value.Value <=129, "blue", "yellow")
```

I have also tried to add this to the 'Format' property of the chart but i am still unable to see this formatting.

Am i missing something?  Can anyone suggest a working solution or another method?

Regards
Betty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work OK? I replicated by setting an expression under **Data Field** -> **Properties** -> **Appearance** -> **Series Style** -> **Fill** -> **Color**.

```
=IIf(Fields!val.Value < 150, "Red", "Blue")
```

So something like:

[image]

Final result:

[image]

Only other consideration is that, depending on your underlying data, you might need an aggregate in the expression:

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!val.Value) < 150, "Red", "Blue")
```

But you can see that it should be possible.

Comment: Many Thanks Ian,  that works a treat.  Its been driving me crazy, searching around on the net for help for a simple task.  you have been a big help.